# What is the difference between Integer Quadratic Programming versus Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, branch-and-bound

I am new to the optimization problem of Quadratic programming.
In equation 8 of the following paper: [here](http://acberg.com/papers/berg_correspondence_cvpr.pdf) , there is an equation:

[image]

The authors state that this is an `'Integer Quadratic Programming (IQP)'` formula.

Alternatively, in another website: [here](https://tomopt.com/docs/models/tomlab_models007.php) , there is the following equation which is described as a '`Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming` (`MIQP`)' formulation:

[image]

From my perspective, both of the equations shown above are similar, with the only difference being that the `MIQP` formula has '1/2' included in it.

1) I am looking for an explanation on the differences between the `IQP` and `MIQP`

2) In addition, I am interested to apply quadratic programming to the assignment problem, thus, looking for any insight into which should be used (i.e., `IQP` vs. `MIQP`) and when.

Comment: Looks like a question for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integer Quadratic Programming** (IQP) implies there are no continuous variables in the model: all variables are discrete. **Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming** (MIQP) allows both discrete and continuous variables. If your model only has discrete variables it is both an MIQP and an IQP. All popular solvers are of the MIQP type, so I tend to use MIQP even if I don't have continuous variables. IQP as model type is not often used. I don't think this is really something to worry about.

Comment: Erwin, so would you say that if MIQP was used in the paper (with Equation 8  posted above) that it would give the exact same solution as IQP ? Also would you be able to point me to a simple comparison of MIQP vs IQP in Python or R.

Comment: Erwin, I do not have enough experience in QP to know what's out there in terms solvers. On another note, not sure if you know any source off-hand that you can point me to, but I am also looking for an example of the assignment problem using MIQP. Cheers.

Comment: As said, this is largely a non-issue. There is no reason not to use a MIQP solver for pure integer problems. There are many different assignment problems, so this is difficult to answer.